# Playing real time audio stream with minimum delay

Tags: android, audio, streaming, real-time

We are developing some sort of intercom system. We need to play real time audio stream in android application using `RTSP` or `HTTP` protocol with minimum delay. Standard approach with `MediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL)` gives too big delays (about 2-3 seconds); We are using `android 2.2`. As i understood size of buffer in media player can be set only on firmware level. Can you give me some advise how to make this or I should go deep in `real VoIP`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found flexible solution - to use AudioTrack API. Also interesting article about audio API available in Android: http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/07/13/Intro-to-the-three-Android-Audio-APIs.aspx